create consecutive dates ranges from 2 tables using SQL
I want to identify the relevant periods from the two tables and create a sequence combination between the two. Every time a change occurs, I want a new record to be made.
First Table:
81080,"segment_name1","2024-04-01 02:05:53.549000000","2024-04-05 08:05:05.000000000"
81080,"segment_name2","2024-04-05 08:05:06.828000000","2024-04-08 08:06:46.000000000"
81080,"segment_name3","2024-04-08 08:06:47.406000000","2024-04-10 08:05:07.000000000"
81080,"segment_name2","2024-04-10 08:05:08.085000000","2024-04-23 14:05:34.000000000"
81080,"segment_name4","2024-04-23 14:05:35.308000000","2024-04-24 08:05:56.000000000"
81080,"segment_name5","2024-04-24 08:05:57.618000000","2024-12-31 23:59:59.000000000"

Second Table:
81080,  "promo1", "2024-04-01 07:00:00","2024-04-02 07:00:00"
81080,  "promo1", "2024-04-02 07:00:00","2024-04-03 07:00:00"
81080,  "promo1", "2024-04-03 07:00:00","2024-04-04 07:00:00"
81080,  "promo1", "2024-04-04 07:00:00","2024-04-05 07:00:00"
81080,  "promo1", "2024-04-05 07:00:00","2024-04-06 07:00:00"
81080,  "promo1", "2024-04-06 13:30:00","2024-04-07 07:00:00"
81080,  "promo1", "2024-04-07 07:00:00","2024-04-09 07:00:00"
81080,  "promo1", "2024-04-08 07:00:00","2024-04-09 07:00:00"
81080,  "promo2", "2024-04-08 07:00:00","2024-07-09 07:00:00"
81080,  "promo1", "2024-04-09 07:00:00","2024-04-10 07:00:00"


desired table:
81080,  "segment_name1",[],"2024-04-01 02:05:53.549" ,"2024-04-01 07:00:00"
81080,  "segment_name1",[promo1] ,"2024-04-01 07:00:00" ,"2024-04-05 08:05:06.828"
81080,  "segment_name2",[promo1],"2024-04-05 08:05:06.828","2024-04-06 07:00:00"
81080,  "segment_name2",[],"2024-04-06 07:00:00","2024-04-06 13:30:00"
81080,  "segment_name2",[promo1],"2024-04-06 13:30:00","2024-04-08 07:00:00"
81080,  "segment_name2",[promo1,promo2],"2024-04-08 07:00:00","2024-04-08 08:06:46.000"
81080,  "segment_name3",[promo1,promo2],"2024-04-08 08:06:47.000","2024-04-10 07:00:00"
81080,  "segment_name3",[promo2],"2024-04-10 07:00:00","2024-04-10 08:05:07.000"
81080,  "segment_name2",[promo2],"2024-04-10 08:05:08.000","2024-04-23 14:05:34.000"
81080,  "segment_name4",[promo2],"2024-04-23 14:05:35.308","2024-04-24 08:05:56.000"
81080,  "segment_name5",[promo2],"024-04-24 08:05:57.618","2024-12-31 23:59:59.000"

i tried to connect the 2 tables and the best way i managed to get closer to solution was by doing this join:
from first_table a left join second_table b on a.segment_id=b.segment_id
                          and a.start_time<=b.end_date
                          and a.end_time>=b.start_date


Tough one.
from pyspark.sql.functions import (
    array,    
    array_distinct,
    array_sort,
    col,    
    collect_set,
    explode_outer,    
    flatten,    
    greatest,
    lead,    
    least,
    lit,    
    min,
    max,
    sum,    
    when
)
from pyspark.sql.types import TimestampType

from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# fmt: off
data_a = [
    (81080, "segment_name1", "2024-04-01 02:05:53.549000000", "2024-04-05 08:05:05.000000000"),
    (81080, "segment_name2", "2024-04-05 08:05:06.828000000", "2024-04-08 08:06:46.000000000"),
    (81080, "segment_name3", "2024-04-08 08:06:47.406000000", "2024-04-10 08:05:07.000000000"),
    (81080, "segment_name2", "2024-04-10 08:05:08.085000000", "2024-04-23 14:05:34.000000000"),
    (81080, "segment_name4", "2024-04-23 14:05:35.308000000", "2024-04-24 08:05:56.000000000"),
    (81080, "segment_name5", "2024-04-24 08:05:57.618000000", "2024-12-31 23:59:59.000000000"),
]

schema_a = ["segment_id", "segment", "segment_start", "segment_end"]
df_a = spark.createDataFrame(data_a, schema_a)
df_a = df_a.withColumn(
    "segment_start", df_a["segment_start"].cast(TimestampType())
).withColumn("segment_end", df_a["segment_end"].cast(TimestampType()))
# fmt: on

data_b = [
    (81080, "promo1", "2024-04-01 07:00:00", "2024-04-02 07:00:00"),
    (81080, "promo1", "2024-04-02 07:00:00", "2024-04-03 07:00:00"),
    (81080, "promo1", "2024-04-03 07:00:00", "2024-04-04 07:00:00"),
    (81080, "promo1", "2024-04-04 07:00:00", "2024-04-05 07:00:00"),
    (81080, "promo1", "2024-04-05 07:00:00", "2024-04-06 07:00:00"),
    (81080, "promo1", "2024-04-06 13:30:00", "2024-04-07 07:00:00"),
    (81080, "promo1", "2024-04-07 07:00:00", "2024-04-09 07:00:00"),
    (81080, "promo1", "2024-04-08 07:00:00", "2024-04-09 07:00:00"),
    (81080, "promo2", "2024-04-08 07:00:00", "2024-07-09 07:00:00"),
    (81080, "promo1", "2024-04-09 07:00:00", "2024-04-10 07:00:00"),
]

schema_b = ["segment_id", "promo", "promo_start", "promo_end"]
df_b = spark.createDataFrame(data_b, schema_b)
df_b = df_b.withColumn(
    "promo_start", df_b["promo_start"].cast(TimestampType())
).withColumn("promo_end", df_b["promo_end"].cast(TimestampType()))

df_interval_overlap = (
    df_a.hint("range_join", 10000000)
    .join(
        df_b,
        (
            (df_a["segment_id"] == df_b["segment_id"])
            & (df_a["segment_start"] <= df_b["promo_end"])
            & (df_a["segment_end"] >= df_b["promo_start"])
        ),
        "inner",
    )
    .select(
        df_a["segment_id"],
        df_a["segment"],
        df_a["segment_start"],
        df_a["segment_end"],
        df_b["promo"],
        df_b["promo_start"],
        df_b["promo_end"],
    )
)

df_island = (
    df_interval_overlap.select(
        "segment_id",
        "segment",
        "promo",
        greatest("segment_start", "promo_start").alias("overlap_start"),
        least("segment_end", "promo_end").alias("overlap_end"),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "previous_end",
        max("overlap_end").over(
            Window.partitionBy("segment_id", "segment", "promo")
            .orderBy("segment_id", "segment", "promo", "overlap_start", "overlap_end")
            .rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow - 1)
        ),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "island_start_indicator",
        when(col("previous_end") >= col("overlap_start"), lit(0)).otherwise(lit(1)),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "island_id",
        sum("island_start_indicator").over(
            Window.orderBy(
                "segment_id", "segment", "promo", "overlap_start", "overlap_end"
            )
        ),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "island_start", min("overlap_start").over(Window.partitionBy(col("island_id")))
    )
    .withColumn(
        "island_end", max("overlap_end").over(Window.partitionBy(col("island_id")))
    )
    .select(
        col("segment_id").alias("island_segment_id"),
        col("segment").alias("island_segment"),
        col("promo").alias("island_promo"),
        col("island_start"),
        col("island_end"),
    )
    .distinct()
)

df_report = (
    df_island.withColumn("date_array", array(col("island_start"), col("island_end")))
    .drop("island_start", "island_end")
    .groupBy(col("island_segment_id"), col("island_segment"))
    .agg(
        collect_set(col("date_array")).alias("date_array"),
        collect_set(col("island_promo")).alias("promo_array"),
    )
    .withColumn("date_array", array_distinct(flatten(col("date_array"))))
    .select(
        "island_segment_id",
        "island_segment",
        explode_outer("promo_array").alias("report_promo"),
        "date_array",
    )
    .select(
        "island_segment_id",
        "island_segment",
        "report_promo",
        explode_outer("date_array").alias("report_start"),
    )
    .withColumn(
        "report_end",
        lead("report_start").over(
            Window.partitionBy(
                "island_segment_id", "island_segment", "report_promo"
            ).orderBy("report_start")
        ),
    )
    .where(col("report_end").isNotNull())
    .drop("report_promo")
    .drop_duplicates()
    .withColumnRenamed("island_segment_id", "report_segment_id")
    .withColumnRenamed("island_segment", "report_segment")
    .orderBy("report_segment_id", "report_segment", "report_start", "report_end")
)


df_result = (
    df_report.join(
        df_island,
        (
            (df_island["island_segment_id"] == df_report["report_segment_id"])
            & (df_island["island_segment"] == df_report["report_segment"])
            & (df_island["island_start"] < df_report["report_end"])
            & (df_island["island_end"] > df_report["report_start"])
        ),
        "left",
    )
    .select(
        col("report_segment_id").alias("segment_id"),
        col("island_promo").alias("promo"),
        col("report_segment").alias("segment"),
        col("report_start").alias("start"),
        col("report_end").alias("end"),
    )
    .groupBy("segment_id", "segment", "start", "end")
    .agg(collect_set("promo").alias("promo"))
    .select("segment_id", "segment", array_sort("promo").alias("promo"), "start", "end")
)


df_a_min_row = (
    df_a.withColumn(
        "min_segment_start",
        min("segment_start").over(
            Window.orderBy("segment_start").rowsBetween(
                Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing
            )
        ),
    )
    .where(col("segment_start") == col("min_segment_start"))
    .drop("min_segment_start")
)

min_segment_start = df_a_min_row.select("segment_start").collect()[0][0]
min_result_segment_start = df_result.select(min("start")).collect()[0][0]

if min_result_segment_start > min_segment_start:
    df_result = df_result.union(
        df_a_min_row.select(
            "segment_id",
            "segment",
            array(),
            lit(min_segment_start),
            lit(min_result_segment_start),
        )
    )

df_a_max_row = (
    df_a.withColumn(
        "max_segment_end",
        max("segment_end").over(
            Window.orderBy(col("segment_end")).rowsBetween(
                Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.unboundedFollowing
            )
        ),
    )
    .where(col("segment_end") == col("max_segment_end"))
    .drop("max_segment_end")
)

max_segment_end = df_a_max_row.select("segment_end").collect()[0][0]
max_result_segment_end = df_result.select(max("end")).collect()[0][0]

if max_result_segment_end < max_segment_end:
    df_result = df_result.union(
        df_a_max_row.select(
            "segment_id",
            "segment",
            array(),
            lit(max_result_segment_end),
            lit(max_segment_end),
        )
    )

df_final_result = df_result.orderBy("segment_id", "segment", "start", "end")
df_final_result.show(truncate=False)

+----------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|segment_id|segment      |promo           |start                  |end                    |
+----------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+
|81080     |segment_name1|[]              |2024-04-01 02:05:53.549|2024-04-01 07:00:00    |
|81080     |segment_name1|[promo1]        |2024-04-01 07:00:00    |2024-04-05 08:05:05    |
|81080     |segment_name2|[promo1]        |2024-04-05 08:05:06.828|2024-04-06 07:00:00    |
|81080     |segment_name2|[]              |2024-04-06 07:00:00    |2024-04-06 13:30:00    |
|81080     |segment_name2|[promo1]        |2024-04-06 13:30:00    |2024-04-08 07:00:00    |
|81080     |segment_name2|[promo1, promo2]|2024-04-08 07:00:00    |2024-04-08 08:06:46    |
|81080     |segment_name2|[]              |2024-04-08 08:06:46    |2024-04-10 08:05:08.085|
|81080     |segment_name2|[promo2]        |2024-04-10 08:05:08.085|2024-04-23 14:05:34    |
|81080     |segment_name3|[promo1, promo2]|2024-04-08 08:06:47.406|2024-04-10 07:00:00    |
|81080     |segment_name3|[promo2]        |2024-04-10 07:00:00    |2024-04-10 08:05:07    |
|81080     |segment_name4|[promo2]        |2024-04-23 14:05:35.308|2024-04-24 08:05:56    |
|81080     |segment_name5|[promo2]        |2024-04-24 08:05:57.618|2024-07-09 07:00:00    |
|81080     |segment_name5|[]              |2024-07-09 07:00:00    |2024-12-31 23:59:59    |
+----------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------+-----------------------+

